# Python match string in loop

Tags: python

```
apdb = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'varagu',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.400',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:11'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'thinai',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.500',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:22'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'Ragi',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.600',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:33'}]}


ap_database = apdb.get('AP Database')

apall = ap_database[0], ap_database[1], ap_database[2]

for ap in apall:

    public = ap.__getitem__('Public IP')
    name = ap.__getitem__('Name')
    ip_list = ['100.20.300.400', '100.20.300.500', '100.20.300.700']
    for ip in ip_list:
        if ip == public:
            print public  + ' ' + name + ' ' + "Success"
```

I am stuck with this. I need to map 'ip' with 'public'.

Expected Result:

Result 1: (This needs to be stored in a variable, since i need to send this in a mail body)

100.20.300.400 Varagu Success

100.20.300.500 Thinai Success

Result 2: (This needs to be stored in a variable and also to be send in seperate mail)

100.20.300.600 Ragi Fail

Comment: `===` doesnt exist on Python

Comment: sorry thats Typo error. its == only.  Thanks for the correction !!!

Comment: Can you show us your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below with some few inline comments

```
apdb = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
              'Name': 'varagu',
              'Public IP': '100.20.300.400',
              'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:11'},
             {'AP Type': '110H',
              'Name': 'thinai',
              'Public IP': '100.20.300.500',
              'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:22'},
             {'AP Type': '110H',
              'Name': 'Ragi',
              'Public IP': '100.20.300.600',
              'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:33'}]}


ap_database = apdb.get('AP Database')

# no need to do this since ap_database is already a list, so we can iterate over it.
# apall = ap_database[0], ap_database[1], ap_database[2]

# ip_list does not change, so we can define it once outside the loop
ip_list = ['100.20.300.400', '100.20.300.500', '100.20.300.700']

# let us add two more variables to hold the fail and success list
success_list = []
fail_list = []

for ap in ap_database:

    # ap is a dict, so use ap.get('key') or ap['key'] instead of ap.__getitem__('key')
    # note that ap.get('key') returns None if key does not exist, while ap['key'] throws an error.
    public = ap.get('Public IP')
    name = ap.get('Name')

    # check whether public is in ip_list and print appropriate message
    if public in ip_list:
        print public, name, 'Success'
        success_list.append(ap)
    else:
        print public, name, 'Fail'
        fail_list.append(ap)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! i need the result separately for success and fail in the respective variable.  Since, i have to include the success result in separate email body and fail result in separate email body.

Comment: are you using python to send out the emails? if so you just have to use `fail_list` and `success_list` to generate the email bodies.

Comment: yes, i am going to use python to send out emails.  Thanks for your help. I am happy with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

While parsing apdb, you can check if 'Public IP' is in `ip_list` and then append the `failed_ip` or `succeed_ip` list.

Then, you just have to process these two lists:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

apdb = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'varagu',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.400',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:11'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'thinai',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.500',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:22'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'Ragi',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.600',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:33'}]}


ap_database = apdb.get('AP Database')

apall = ap_database[0], ap_database[1], ap_database[2]
ip_list = ['100.20.300.400', '100.20.300.500', '100.20.300.700']
succeed_ip = []
failed_ip = []
for ap in apall:
    success = None
    failed = None
    public = ap.__getitem__('Public IP')
    name = ap.__getitem__('Name')
    if public in ip_list:
        succeed_ip.append((public, name))
        continue
    failed_ip.append((public, name))

print succeed_ip
print failed_ip

table = PrettyTable(['IP', 'Name', 'Result'])
table.add_row(succeed_ip[0])
table.add_row(succeed_ip[1])
print(table)

ftable = PrettyTable(['IP', 'Name', 'Result'])
ftable.add_row(failed_ip[0])
print(ftable)
```

### Result:

```
[('100.20.300.400', 'varagu', 'success'), ('100.20.300.500', 'thinai', 'success')]
[('100.20.300.600', 'Ragi', 'Failed')]
+----------------+--------+---------+
|       IP       |  Name  |  Result |
+----------------+--------+---------+
| 100.20.300.400 | varagu | success |
| 100.20.300.500 | thinai | success |
+----------------+--------+---------+
+----------------+------+--------+
|       IP       | Name | Result |
+----------------+------+--------+
| 100.20.300.600 | Ragi | Failed |
+----------------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for the help !!! I am planning to put the result in a table format and send in mail.

Comment: I have updated the script and added the result as well. I got the result and expected. But the thing is , i need to mention the table.add_row(succeed_ip[0])
table.add_row(succeed_ip[1]                                                                                 to get the result. Is it possible to get the result without mentioning the index range? since, i might include more list in future so that i dont have to add the index. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked your code little bit:
1) `apall = ap_database[0], ap_database[1], ap_database[2]` this assignment is not necessary, since  `ap_database = apdb.get('AP Database')` this will make ap_database already a list

2) `ip_list = ['100.20.300.400', '100.20.300.500', '100.20.300.700']` this should be out of the loop and no need for reassignment for each loop cycle

3) instead of the 2 lines below, you can directly search for public ip in the ip_list like: `if public in ip_list:`

```
for ip in ip_list:
        if ip == public:
```

4) and instead of using **getitem** it's more readable for me to just use get method (just for me, if you prefer, you can use **getitem**)

```
apdb = {'AP Database': [{'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'varagu',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.400',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:11'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'thinai',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.500',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:22'},
                 {'AP Type': '110H',
                  'Name': 'Ragi',
                  'Public IP': '100.20.300.600',
                  'Wired MAC Address': 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:33'}]}

ap_database = apdb.get('AP Database')
ip_list = ['100.20.300.400', '100.20.300.500', '100.20.300.700']
results = {'success': [], 'fail': []}

for ap in ap_database:
    public = ap.get('Public IP')
    name = ap.get('Name')
    if public in ip_list:
        results['success'].append(public)
    else:
        results['fail'].append(public)

print(results['success'], reuslts['fail'])
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I am able to see only the Success result, need the failed in as well. i need the result separately for success and fail in the respective variable.  Since, i have to include the success result in separate email body and fail result in separate email body to send email.

Comment: ok, added results variable to access the 'success' and 'fail' values for later use